# Reading the data from a csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, r-markdown

I want to read some data from a csv file in R in order to compute a t-test function but I didn't success to do that and accoriding to the debugger, the arguments are not numeric or logical: returning NA.

This is the code of the t-test without reading from the csv file:

```
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data <- list(c(99, 52), c(96, 40), c(100, 38), c(105, 18), 
             c(NA_integer_, 11), c(NA_integer_, 5), c(NA_integer_, 42), 
             c(NA_integer_, 55), c(NA_integer_, 53), c(NA_integer_, 39),
             c(NA_integer_, 42), c(NA_integer_, 50))

df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    

                           
                           
results <- t.test(df[['non-failing heart (NF)']], df[['failing heart (F)']])


                           
results$statistic
results$estimate
results$p.value
```

and this is what I've tried:

```
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data <- read.csv2(file="C:\\Users\\alex\\Downloads\\data.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE)


df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    

                           
                           
results <- t.test(df[['non-failing heart (NF)']], df[['failing heart (F)']])


                           
results$statistic
results$estimate
results$p.value
```

This is how my file "data.csv" looks like:

[image: data.csv]

Then it will be visualized in Boxplot using this code:

```
df$NF <- df$`non-failing heart (NF)`
df$F <- df$`failing heart (F)`
boxplot(df[3:4],
        data=df,
        cex.lab=0.65,
        xlab="Fig. 1 IRE binding activity for non-failing (NF) and failing (F) hearts.",
        ylab="IRE binding activity (%)",
        col="orange",
        border="brown",
        ylim = c(0, 120)
)
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need `setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame.....` part? Isn't `data` a dataframe already?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks for trying to help me. yes *data* is already a dataframe, because it worked in the first one, I thought I need it maybe by importing it from the csv

Comment: What you have in first one is a list whereas when you use `read.csv`/`read.csv2` you get a dataframe. Try `t.test(data$\`non-failing heart (NF)\`, data$\`failing heart (F)\`)` Or `t.test(data[['non-failing heart (NF)']], data[['failing heart (F)']])` should work as well.

Comment: @RonakShah I tried that but it didn't work, shall I remove the **df <- setNames** ?

Comment: Yes, I think you don't need that line at all. 1) `data <- read.csv2....` 2) `t.test(data[['non-failing heart (NF)']], data[['failing heart (F)']])`

Comment: @RonakShah I checked again my code, sorry forget to mention that I need the **df** later in visualizing the data in a Boxplot *(I edit my question, you can see now the code of the plot)*

Comment: Can you include `dput(head(data, 10))` in your post?

Comment: @RonakShah I put it direct after **data <- read.csv2**, I still got some error as **Error in x[floor(d)] + x[ceiling(d)]**

Comment: So you are not able to read the data properly in R at the first place? Do you need `read.csv` instead of `read.csv2` ? Is your file comma delimited or semi-colon?

Comment: @RonakShah, after adding the line that you gave me, I am getting this output : **structure(list(NF = c("99", "96", "100", "105", "NA_integer_", 
"NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_"
), F = c(52L, 40L, 38L, 18L, 11L, 5L, 42L, 55L, 53L, 39L)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")** So I think the probelm now with reading this data as number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `'NA_integer_'` as a string. Turn them to actual `NA` values and then perform `t.test`.

```
data[data == 'NA_integer_'] <- NA
t.test(data$NF, data$F)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I add the two lines after **data <-read**, I am getting wrong values in the plot

Comment: @Anouar You should ask only one question per post. Keep this post related to `t.test` and ask another question for plotting if needed.

Comment: ok sorry just thought that the plot is a way to verify if the t-test works fine ir not, but as I see, your answer is coorect for the t-test problem.

Answer (score 0):

```r
read.csv(file = 'your path')
data <- read.csv2(file="C:/Users/alex/Downloads/data.csv", sep=";", dec=".", header=TRUE)
```

Try using `/` instead of `\`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help would be useful to be able to read this like code (including line-wraps). Bottom line, you can preface your code block with `\`\`\`lang-r` (on its own line) and close out the code block with `\`\`\`` (again, its own line).

Comment: @Perry thanks for trying to help me, but I already tried that and it didn't work