# Compute t-test in R via reading csv data and visualize it in Boxplot

Tags: r, r-markdown, boxplot, t-test

I am trying to import some data from a csv file and visualize it in a Boxplot to display it again online using a plateform.
I am using R as developing language for computing a t-test function then displaying the results in plot.
I am getting this error when I try to compute the t-test :
[image: Error]

This is the code what I wrote it:

```
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
data[data == 'NA_integer_'] <- NA
t.test(data$NF, data$F)

df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    

                           
                           
results <- t.test(data$`non-failing heart (NF)`, data$`failing heart (F)`)


                           
results$statistic
results$estimate
results$p.value
                           

df$NF <- df$`non-failing heart (NF)`
df$F <- df$`failing heart (F)`
boxplot(df[3:4],
        data=df,
        cex.lab=0.65,
        xlab="Fig. 1 IRE binding activity for non-failing (NF) and failing (F) hearts.",
        ylab="IRE binding activity (%)",
        col="orange",
        border="brown",
        ylim = c(0, 120)
)
```

*Sample Data*

```
structure(list(NF = c("99", "96", "100", "105", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_" ), F = c(52L, 40L, 38L, 18L, 11L, 5L, 42L, 55L, 53L, 39L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

*Update*

After converting the data to numeric as mention in the answer, I am getting this error:
[image: Error 2]

Comment: Can you share some rows of your data.csv, so we can try running the code?

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro yes sure, after adding **dput** : structure(list(NF = c("99", "96", "100", "105", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_" ), F = c(52L, 40L, 38L, 18L, 11L, 5L, 42L, 55L, 53L, 39L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: you should convert the column to numeric

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk I tried it, but it doesn't work, do you have an idea how ?

Comment: @Anouar `as.numeric(df$NF)` didn't work? it should pop a warning message "Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion" but it should work

Comment: @RicardoSemiãoeCastro can you explain more please, where should I put this line to convert the data

Comment: @Anouar what plateform are you using?

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Stencila

Comment: @Anouar please add the code u used for creating `results`

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Actually this is the hole code, in the folllowing post you will find mybe more details about the data : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64363028/reading-the-data-from-a-csv-file-in-r/64364427?noredirect=1#comment113825718_64364427

Comment: ok the. error is coming from using data inside t.test call, you need to change it to df

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223171/discussion-between-anouar-and-abdessabour-mtk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to turn all the columns to numeric type:

```r
# add this line after data[data == 'NA_integer_']
library(tidyverse)
data %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) -> data
```

And change the data.frame you're using to calculate result

```r
# change data with df
results <- t.test(df$`non-failing heart (NF)`, df$`failing heart (F)`)
```

#### full code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.6.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.2
labels <- list('non-failing heart (NF)', 'failing heart (F)')

data<-structure(list(NF = c("99", "96", "100", "105", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_", "NA_integer_" ), F = c(52L, 40L, 38L, 18L, 11L, 5L, 42L, 55L, 53L, 39L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
data[data == 'NA_integer_'] <- NA
data %>% mutate_all(as.numeric) -> data
t.test(data$NF, data$F)
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  data$NF and data$F
#> t = 10.866, df = 10.695, p-value = 4.118e-07
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  51.54831 77.85169
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>     100.0      35.3
df <- setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, 
                       lapply(data, function(d) data.frame(d[1], d[2]))),
              labels)    

                           
                           
results <- t.test(df$`non-failing heart (NF)`, df$`failing heart (F)`)

                           
results$statistic
#>         t 
#> 0.2051717
results$estimate
#> mean of x mean of y 
#>      75.5      68.0
results$p.value
#> [1] 0.8569285
                           

df$NF <- df$`non-failing heart (NF)`
df$F <- df$`failing heart (F)`
boxplot(df[3:4],
        data=df,
        cex.lab=0.65,
        xlab="Fig. 1 IRE binding activity for non-failing (NF) and failing (F) hearts.",
        ylab="IRE binding activity (%)",
        col="orange",
        border="brown",
        ylim = c(0, 120)
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, I tried your suggestion but I am getting this error :
**{"statistic":[6.6364],"parameter":[11],"p.value":[0],"conf.int":["[1] 4.065764 8.100903\nattr(,\"conf.level\")\n[1] 0.95"],"estimate":[6.0833],"null.value":[0],"stderr":[0.9167],"alternative":["two.sided"],"method":["One Sample t-test"],"data.name":["data$NF"]}
not enough 'x' observations
object 'results' not found
object 'results' not found
object 'results' not found**

Comment: can you add it to the question and show from where the error is coming?